# Cartalyst Stripe package implementation to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am implementing Cartalyst Stripe to my laravel app.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#installation

This is my controller code at index method:

```
$stripe = new Stripe(env('STRIPE_API_KEY'));

        $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
            'email' => Auth::user()->email,
            'name' => Auth::user()->name
        ]);

        $token = $stripe->tokens()->create([
            'card' => [
                'number'    => '4242424242424242',
                'exp_month' => 6,
                'exp_year'  => 2022,
                'cvc'       => 314,
            ],
        ]);

        $card = $stripe->cards()->create($customer['id'], $token['id']);

        $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
            'customer' => $customer['id'],
            'currency' => Session::get('appcurrency'),
            'amount' => Session::get('total_payment'),
            'statement_descriptor' => 'Descriptor.com'
        ]);
```

I will use this bootstrap form to collect user info, so I ll pass all users input thru $request later (there will be month and year for expiration separated later, but its not important for now):

```
<form action="{{  \LaravelLocalization::localizeURL('/order-final') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('post')


<div class="section">
    <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"><label>Card number:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="card_number" placeholder="Card number" value=""></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mt-5"><label>Expiration:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="expiration_date" placeholder="Expiration"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mt-5"><label>CVC:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cvc" placeholder=" CVC"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mt-5"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="card-button">Pay</button></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So, once I make this test charge, everything works very good, so implementation is successful.
I am just trying to figure out, how to handle card where is 3D Secure required, because I want to make 3D Secure required for all payments, especially from SCA countries.
I tried to do that with paymentintent and setup intent, but I have no idea.
I want to let customers fill out card details, then it should be redirected to stripe 3D secure page and then redirected back to some url.
At payment intent is parameter return_url, but I have no idea how to set it up.
Never did stripe before.
I can use stripe without 3D secure now, which is okay, but I want to use 3D Secure.
I tried to use Stripe's form with Stripe.js:

```
 <div id="card-element">
```

But it always mess up my bootstrap 5 code, so that redirect will be fine.
I also thought about Stripe Billing portal option and redirect customers to the stripe billing portal directly.
Also, I want to use customer's card in stripe, which works as well, just having that 3D secure issue.
So I just somehow need to trigger Stripe SCA redirection for authentication.
Can you help me, please?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reach out to Cartalyst for more detailed support, but at a high level it appears to largely act as a thin wrapper around the underlying `stripe-php` package ([github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)).

You need to read about [migrating to Payment Intents from Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) in order to support SCA/3D Secure properly, or the Accept a Payment [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-create-payment-intent).

While you *can* use the `return_url` for [manual 3DS redirect handling](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#manual-redirect), this is not recommended. Using the Stripe.js client-side helper `confirmCardPayment` ([guide step](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment)) is likely to lead to a better integration experience.

Comment: yeah I figured this out. U just need to use $session for stripe checkout. bot options are working to me now. thanks for help